# Serialization Issue with WF4

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, datacontract, xaml-serialization

I have a peculiar issue with a variable in my workflow service. It is an array of a datacontract from a REST service, `ContactContract[]`. When this array is empty everything is great and the workflow continues on correctly. However, if there are any items in the array a stack overflow occurs outside of my activities, I can't pinpoint the specific spot unfortunately.

So, having seen something like this before with the `DataContractSerializer` when cycles exist in the object graph I wrote a unit test to try it out. The test fails with the following exception:

> System.Xaml.XamlObjectReaderException: Unable to serialize type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject'.  Verify that the
>   type is public and either has a default constructor or an instance
>   descriptor.

And the test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ContactArraySerialize()
{
    var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ContactContract[]));
    var reader = new StringReader(Strings.SERIALIZED_CONTACT_LIST);
    var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader);
    var list = ser.ReadObject(xmlReader) as ContactContract[];

    var str = XamlServices.Save(list);
}
```

(I would add the xml for the contact list but it's huge)

I gather this is because the contract implements `IExtensibleDataObject` to support versioning a bit better.

This is not the stack overflow I had anticipated, but I bet it is related.

Has anyone encountered either of these issues or have any advice?

Comment: Hard to say without a peek at ContactContract.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I feel like an idiot now. Turns out it wasn’t the workflow crashing but the WcfTestClient b/c it couldn’t figure out how to display the contact contract.